# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: bpfilter read fail: 0 when shutting down w/kernel 5.16.13

Tags: kernel, suspend

Installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on an Acer Swift 3 notebook (model SF314-42-R6T7).  With the included 5.13.0-30 and also the newer 5.13.0-35 generic kernels, Suspend did not work correctly.  Machine would Suspend with a press of the power button, but there was a long delay - up to a minute or so - for the machine to wake up after pressing the power button again.

I installed a newer kernel, 5.16.13 and now Suspend works as expected (except when closing the lid with an external monitor connected, but that's for another thread).  However, when doing either a restart or shutdown, I get a minute or more of zillions of messages like the following:

```
[114.588698] bpfilter read fail: 0
```

I believe the number is system uptime.  I get these messages constantly for as much as a minute and a half before the machine finally restarts or shuts off.

So far I tried:

--rebooting into the older kernels (5.13.0 and 5.13.35) using the GRUB menu.  with both choices, Suspend again doesn't work right, but I don't get the bpfilter messages when shutting down or restarting.

So it seems like this bpfilter problem was definitely introduced with the newer kernel.

Going back to the older 5.13 kernel(s) does fix the bpfilter messages, but then Suspend does not work properly.

Is there any way to get rid of the bpfilter messages which are delaying shutdown, while keeping the 5.6.13 kernel so that Suspend works properly?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Ubuntu forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2472909), it's an issue with the iptables support in nftables and something is calling the firewall during shutdown.  On my system it doesn't go on for very long (not even a full screen worth), but hopefully this will be fixed in near-future kernel versions.